# Is there a way to determine if cells are out of order in a jupyter notebook? (e.g., using a variable in one cell that is only declared in a later one)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am hoping to find for example a nbextension that can determine whether jupyter cells would crash if run. I understand this can't be achieved in the general case (halting problem) but I suppose likely culprits, such as out-of-order code, could be found fairly easily. Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Yes for your first sentence (which is different than your title and last sentence), although I cannot come up with a link now. There were studies of `.ipynb` files posted on GitHub and many won't run for various reasons. In general this is easy to do with nbconvert command to execute the notebook in a separate instance. It errors out which you can detect. The specific reasons are much harder to determine. To tell if the notebook was run with cells out of order, a variation on the first issue in your title, you can read in the notebook with nbformat and see of the cells are numbered than ...

Comment: <continued> they should be if you read top to bottom.

Comment: [This article 'Understanding and improving the quality and reproducibility of Jupyter notebooks'](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10664-021-09961-9) covers a lot of what I discuss for basing my answer that much of this is possible. The provide a tool called 'Julynter' that does a lot of the hard lifting to understand issues, see [here](https://dew-uff.github.io/julynter/) for more and links to [the julynter github repo](https://github.com/dew-uff/julynter) where it is documented. If they have other software they offer it may do some of the basics I mention already.

Comment: There's also [nbQA](https://nbqa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but that is more about  examining notebooks for using Python coding standards. I think it may catch things like out of order declarations though.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the links. Do you know of a more general repository for these and similar kinds of resources? (I am always looking for ways to improve my workflow, which relies heavily on jupyter. For example, finding nbextensions was a huge improvement.)

Comment: The Jupyter blog is good to learn about things in the ecosystem. [The Jupyter Community Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) has a 'Show-and-Tell' category.

Comment: I probably should also point to [nbsmoke](https://github.com/pyviz-dev/nbsmoke) and this discussion on [Testing notebooks on the Jupyter Discourse forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/testing-notebooks/701), which includs mention of 'nbval', too.